# About 'Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality'

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality gives gives relations between **moments of a collection of independent random variables**. The statement of this inequality can be seen in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality

However, another better form can be  seen among the top six lines on the left column in Page 5 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4626v1.pdf . However, the related citation **Burkholder, D. L. Sharp inequalities for martingales
and stochastic integrals** can not be easily accessed on Internet. Could anyone rigorously restate the details of this form of Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality?

Answer (score 1):

[See this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4849.pdf). For example theorem 5.3 should give you what you want.